# Different routes on clicking different buttons from the same component

Tags: angular

I have 3 components in my angular app - signin, markets and register. The sign in component is my landing component. I have two buttons on the sign in page - sign in and sign up. Clicking the sign in button should take me to the market component and clicking the sign up button shaould take me to the register component. I can navigate to the register component after clicking sign up, but, I cannot navigate to the markets component after clicking sign in. The URL changes to localhost:4200/markets, but, the markets component does not load. The sign in component stays as it is. There are no errors in the console. the snippets for the components are attached.

signin.component.html

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['../markets']">Sign in</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" [routerLink]="['../register']">Sign Up</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

register.component.html

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['../signin']">Register</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.html

```html
<signin></signin>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { MarketsComponent } from './markets/markets.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "signin", component: SigninComponent},
  { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent},
  { path: "markets", component: MarketsComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

[image]

Comment: does your app component has the router outlet component

Comment: app.component.html only has the selector for the sign in component (<signin></signin>). app.module.ts has the app routing module in imports.

Comment: As @HitechHitesh said, You need to use the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag instead of `signin` into the app.component. It says to angular where to put the founded component.
If you want to show signin by default add `{ path: "", redirectTo: "/signin", pathMatch: 'full'},` to your routes.
Here a french but nice article about how routing works: https://wetry.tech/les-secrets-du-router-d-angular/

Answer (score 0):

In the login component/app component inject the router in the constructor

```
// import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

  constructor(private router: Router)
```

the login method `login()` include the command `this.router.navigate` when the login successful.

Comment: There is no login validation. I was just checking if I am able to move to different components from the same component. I have imported the module mentioned. Request you to to elaborate what to do with the this.router.navigate command.

Comment: Did you generate the Markets component using Angular CLI by ng g c ?
if not, did you declare the Markets Components in App Module?
You may also try to use `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['../markets']">Sign in</button>` without .. Like this `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/markets']">Sign in</button>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all your application routing structure has some mismatch, however, I made a simple routing as your per requirement, please check below link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahleui?embed=1&file=src/index.html